# Is it possible to search comments like we can search chat messages?

Tags: support, comments, search

In `chat.stackexchange.com` we can search all chat messages filtered by keywords, user id, and room id.  The search result has unique URL to a chat message.

Given that there is also a unique URL for a comment, is there a similar search page to find comments by keywords and user id within a specific SE site or even across all SE sites?

If there is no special search page for this, is there a sample efficient data query I can use?